# using soundminer on an AUX BUS for monitoring. 

Tags: soundminer

Hi there (first post) 
I wanted to know if anyone knows how to find the vst plug in for soundminer. I cant seem to find it in my mac. Im just trying to put SM on an AUX channel so that i dont have to toggle between inputs on my d-box for monitoring. 
In Pro tools 10 when I go to instrument the re-wire plug is not there.

Im using SM 4 Pro.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using Soundminer v4Pro with PT10 and MBox 3 Pro here and I have no problems using rewire or going out the Core Audio driver (Both of which output through the MBox).

However, from the Help>Soundminer Help menu. A quick search for "rewire" turns up this chunk of useful info from page 16, start here. There are also a number of helpful pictures that I'm not going to bother posting because they're in the SMV4_manual.pdf that the help menu should direct you to.

The last few paragraphs in particular are possibly most important in your situation.

> Pro Tools and REWIRE - The one known exception to using Coreaudio is AVID/Digidesign Pro Tools. The AVID/Digidesign hardware cannot be accessed when the Pro Tools software is running. In response to this change, Soundminer developed a Rewire based connection option. When Pro Tools is running, playback via the AVID/Digidesign hardware is only possible through Rewire as Pro Tools does not allow sharing of their hardware. Rewire is a third party connectivity platform. To use Rewire, make sure your sound control preferences is set to ‘Built-in’. Do the same in your Audio/Midi Utility application(Application/Utilities). As a final preparation, make sure your Pro Tools DAE H/W buffer is set to a size compatible with the speed of your computer – the faster the computer, the smaller you can make the buffer size (accessible in your Pro Tools playback engine menu).
>
> Each Soundminer version has a very specific sm4rewire bundle. Do not mix them up. Soundminer will automatically install the correct smv4rewire.bundle when you first launch.
>   To use REWIRE connectivity, the DAW host(Pro Tools in this example) must be launched first. You must then open a track (AUX) in Pro Tools and insert the Soundminer Engine from your multi-channel RTAS instrument plug-in options.
>
> Assign the Soundminer Left/Right outputs to your channel/Aux and route that Channel/Aux to an available hardware output(V4pro will have multi- channel options enabled via multiple plug-in instantiation).
>
> Then launch Soundminer. If connection has been successful, you will be notified and your rewire connection automatically turned on(toggle on/off is at the bottom left of the v4 interface).
>
> In Soundminer, the toggle on/off is now active and audio played in Soundminer will be passed through the Rewire connectivity interface and routed through the DAW’s hardware and outputs:
>
> TROUBLESHOOTING: If your cursor does not play, this would be a good indication that your Sound system Preferences have been set to the Digidesign Core Audio driver and is conflicting with Pro Tools. While this driver works fine to route audio through Digidesign/AVID hardware when Pro Tools is not running, it becomes problematic if enabled and you try to run both Pro Tools and Soundminer. Please turns this off and set it to ‘Built-in’.
>
> REWIRE – For reference, the rewire components are installed in this location:
>
> ~/Library/Application Support/Propellerhead Software/ReWire/SM4Rewire.bundle
>
> ** Rewire is a third party standard created by Propellerheads (makers of Reason). It requires a rewire host (Pro Tools) and a rewire slave(Soundminer). As a slave we have limited control over the connection. V4pro has multi-channel Rewire operation, linked playback and transport control(not yet enabled). V4 has basic two channel stereo rewire only. Use of Rewire for other applications is for the most part similar. Host must always be launched first and quit last. Digidesign Pro Tools installs the necessary RTAS plug-in that allows the host bundle to connect to our slave bundle. If you need to access the Rewire host bundle, go directly to Propellerheads.com(makers of Rewire).

Answer (score 0):

I use it this way.

You create a session, the one that you'll be editing with. Create a stereo aux channel and set the output to your main stereo out (analog 1-2).

If you've installed the plugin correctly and have the license asset on the ilok, then you'll have a soundminer plugin in instruments I believe, in any case, it's an RTAS processor. So, instantiate that on one of the inserts for that aux you created.

Importantly, you need to instantiate the plugin and have the PT session running before you open soundminer, that way the rewire (the tech that allows SM to talk to PT) works. When installing soundminer, it might even ask you to update the rewire client.

your done.

don't forget to solo safe the aux track. CMD + click on solo button. this way if you have any solos in the session it won't cut the output of soundminer.

cruise through your library in soundminer to find good sounds and then once one is found, hit CMD + B and it'll import the file into the pro tools region/clip bin. then you can drag it into the timeline.

you can also just highlight certain parts of the audio in soundminer and only import that part.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone! For some reason the plug in does not exist. Instead I ran the analogue out from my mac into inputs 5-6 on my interface and brought the signal back into the pro tools session via an aux bus. Not as slick as the re-wire plug but i cant find it on my system. Thanks again though 

Comment: Hit "S" and it will spot the sound right where your cursor is in the session. non need to drag from bin.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "rewire" plug-in in the "instruments" category...if I'm remembering correctly. It's automatic for me. It's called SM Engine, or SM Eng...again, autmoatic for me.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone with a similar setup to mine stumbles upon this page. I go from the optical out to the optical in from my mac to digi 003. Then run miniminer as a standalone. make sure my protools setup is spdif. crete input on my 9/10 (spdif) marked "soundminer." Then create an aux solo safed with the input being soundminer. The benefits being that everything is digital and you don't have to switch to an "aux in."